# No conecta el datagridview con SQL

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

estoy intentando conectar con mi base de datos SQL y que me muestre el resultado de la consulta en un datagridview. este es el código que estoy usando pero no veo ningún error y VS no me muestra alguno en en el código.

Esto es parte de una herramienta que se desea que haga otras cosas relacionada con los datos pero no tiene alguna relevancia para esta consulta (creo yo)

Este es el código que estoy usando.

```
using sun.tools.java;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Routing
{
    public partial class inicio : Form
    {
        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("server=CUD1C0O5UT\\SQLEXPRESS; database = Routing; integrated security=true");
        public inicio()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void inicio_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           openFileDialog2.ShowDialog();
        }
        private void pictureBox1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
        }       private void pictureBox1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form formulario = new SANDY();
            formulario.Show();
        }
        private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { try
            {
            conexion.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Conectado");
            }
            catch (exception)
            {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
        }

        private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("Select * from Vader", conexion);
            SqlDataAdapter adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adaptador.SelectCommand = comando;
            DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
            adaptador.Fill(tabla);
            dtgrouting.DataSource = tabla;
        }
    }
}
```

El error que me da VB al buscar mas detalladamente es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Coloca el esquema de tu base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando especificas la cadena de conexión al servidor, por lo general se define la base de datos pero **no el esquema donde estás trabajando**.

Cambia tu sentencia

```
  Select * from Vader
```

por

```
  Select * from dbo.Vader
```

O el esquema donde esa tabla esté. Inténtalo y nos dejas saber

Answer (score 0):

no pude resolver este problema, intente todo lo que se ocurrio y no pude hacerlo, ahora, estaba intentando agregar un modulo para enlazar excel como base datos en un datagridview, pero no encuentro la opcion para agregarlo.
Estoy con la version comunity 2019,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]¿que estoy pasando por alto?

Ya intente agregarlo como elemento, pero no me aparece en la lista para agregarlo.